# get whole count of rows in a query with group condition

Tags: mysql

I need to have a whole number of rows in a query with a  `GROUP` condition. Here is query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM (`exp_channel_titles`)
LEFT JOIN `exp_category_posts` cp ON `cp`.`entry_id`=`exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id`
LEFT JOIN `exp_categories` c ON `cp`.`cat_id`=`c`.`cat_id`
LEFT JOIN `exp_internships_placements` ip ON `ip`.`entry_id`=`exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id`
LEFT JOIN `exp_members` m ON `m`.`member_id`=`exp_channel_titles`.`author_id`
WHERE `exp_channel_titles`.`site_id` =  '8'
AND `exp_channel_titles`.`channel_id` =  '7'
AND (title like '%%')
GROUP BY `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id`
```

and results as

```
numrows
3
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I need to get 12. If I remove `GROUP` condition I get 15 results which is not correct. Can you please advise me how to get it work as I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` and select `COUNT(DISTINCT exp_channel_titles.entry_id)` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id`) AS `numrows`
FROM (`exp_channel_titles`)
LEFT JOIN `exp_category_posts` cp ON `cp`.`entry_id`=`exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id`
LEFT JOIN `exp_categories` c ON `cp`.`cat_id`=`c`.`cat_id`
LEFT JOIN `exp_internships_placements` ip ON `ip`.`entry_id`=`exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id`
LEFT JOIN `exp_members` m ON `m`.`member_id`=`exp_channel_titles`.`author_id`
WHERE `exp_channel_titles`.`site_id` =  '8'
AND `exp_channel_titles`.`channel_id` =  '7'
AND (title like '%%')
```